# values of basic trig function, given values in terms of trig functions

Tags: trigonometry

Get the function value if $\displaystyle \sin x = \frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$ and $\displaystyle \cos x = -\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$ and the function value is going to be calculated from $\displaystyle \sin\left(2x-\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please make sure I formatted you question properly. It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! As you've asked a handful of questions now, but haven't accepted any answers, it might be helpful to know that you can accept one answer per question, and you can upvote as many answers as you'd like. To accept an answer, just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You get two reputation points for each answer you accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin(2x-\frac{7\pi}{6})=\sin2x\cos(7\pi/6)-\cos2x\sin(7\pi/6)=$$
$$=2\sin x\cos x\cos(7\pi/6)-(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)\sin(7\pi/6)=$$
$$=2(2/\sqrt 13)(-3/\sqrt13)\cos(7\pi/6)-(4/13-9/13)\sin(7\pi/6)=$$
$$=-12/13\cos(7\pi/6)+5/13\sin(7\pi/6)=$$
$$=-12/13(-\sqrt 3/2)+5/13(-1/2)=$$
$$=12\sqrt 3/26-5/26=(12\sqrt 3-5)/26$$

Comment: What is the ending of that?

Comment: Answer is edited now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sum and difference formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) to split up $\sin\left(2x-\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)$.  You will then get expressions involving $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$, $\sin\frac{7\pi}{6}$, and $\cos \frac{7\pi}{6}.$